# Blob trigger using event grid in .NET Isolated Worker functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have this `BlobTrigger` that comes from `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` (.NET in-process functions).

```
public class SftpFileUploadTrigger
{
    private readonly IDtoBuilderManager _dtoBuilderManager;

    public SftpFileUploadTrigger(IDtoBuilderManager dtoBuilderManager)
    {
        _dtoBuilderManager = dtoBuilderManager;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(SftpFileUploadTrigger))]
    public async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("%BlobStorageContainers:AzureSftp%/{name}", Source = BlobTriggerSource.EventGrid, Connection = "Storage:ConnectionString")] Stream dataFileBlob,
        string name,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("{FunctionName} function processed blob with name {Name} and size {Length} Bytes", nameof(SftpFileUploadTrigger), name, dataFileBlob.Length);

        // Create data transfer object
        var dataFileCreateDto = _dtoBuilderManager.DataFileCreateDtoBuilder
            .WithName(name)
            .AddSession()
            .WithStatus(DataFileStatus.Pending)
            .WithSessionType(DataFileSessionType.DataFileIntake)
            .WithStartedOn(DateTime.UtcNow)
            .Build();

        // Start data file intake workflow
        string instanceId = await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync(nameof(DataFileIntakeOrchestration), dataFileCreateDto);

        log.LogInformation("Started {OrchestrationName} with id {InstanceId}", nameof(DataFileIntakeOrchestration), instanceId);
    }
}
```

The reason why I used `BlobTriggerSource.EventGrid` is because of the delays when using `BlobTriggerSource.LogsAndContainerScan`. Microsoft does say that it can take up to 10 minutes for the trigger to fire but that is a total lie. Sometimes it took up to an hour so I just setup an event grid and changed the source.

Now I want to migrate this trigger to .NET 7 Isolated Worker functions and I can't seem to find anything in Microsoft's documentation.

I have tried using the `BlobTrigger` from `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` but it does not have a `Source` property so the below code does not work.

```
public class SftpFileUploadTrigger
{
    private readonly ILogger<SftpFileUploadTrigger> _logger;

    public SftpFileUploadTrigger(ILogger<SftpFileUploadTrigger> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(SftpFileUploadTrigger))]
    public async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("%BlobStorageContainers:AzureSftp%/{name}", Source = BlobTriggerSource.EventGrid, Connection = "Storage:ConnectionString")] Stream dataFileBlob,
        string name,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client)
    {
        this._logger.LogInformation("{FunctionName} function processed blob with name {Name} and size {Length} Bytes", nameof(SftpFileUploadTrigger), name, dataFileBlob.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have tried using the `BlobTrigger` from`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` but it does not have a `Source` property**

Yes, `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs` package doesn't have a **`Source`** property as **`Source`** is a part of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` package and isolated function doesn't use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` .

I have used an alternative way to achieve the same by following below steps-

**`code:`**

```
using  System;
using  System.IO;
using  Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace  Company.Function
{
public  class  BlobTriggerEventGrid
{
private  readonly  ILogger  _logger;
public  BlobTriggerEventGrid(ILoggerFactory  loggerFactory)
{
_logger  =  loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BlobTriggerEventGrid>();
}
[Function("BlobTriggerEventGrid")]
public  void  Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}",Connection  =  "afreensa01_STORAGE")] string  myBlob, string  name)
{
_logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name}  \n Data: {myBlob}");
}
}
}
```

Run ngrok using `ngrok.exe http http://localhost:7071` command in cmd and copy `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io`

[image]

As per [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp), your event-driven blob storage trigger should look like `http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName={your function name}`.

Replace `http://localhost:7071` with `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io` and your final endpoint would look like `http://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName={your function name}`.

Make sure before creating event, your function is running locally and ngrok is online too.

[image]

[image]

Use `http://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName={your function name}` endpoint below and click create.

[image]

Once the event is created then you can upload a blob to test if its working.

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have opened a [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/113015) for `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions` package not having **`source`** parameter support. You can refer it for any latest update.